# How to Include molecular geometry into 3D plot in mathematica?

Tags: plot, geometry, wolfram-mathematica, combinations

I am making a ListPlot3D in *Mathematica* in which the energy (z) depends on molecular parameters (x,y). First I import data (2 energy surfaces in x,y,z form):

```
data = Import["D:\2dscan\mrci\GS-data.txt", "Table"];
data2 = Import["D:\2dscan\mrci\1ex-data.txt", "Table"];
```

then visualize the graphics:

```
Show[
ListPlot3D[{data}, PlotRange -> {9, 14}, Mesh -> None, 
ColorFunction ->ColorData["Rainbow"], 
AlignmentPoint -> Center, ViewPoint -> {2, -2, 2},
ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, BoxRatios -> {3, 3, 1}, FaceGrids -> {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}},  
PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {9, 14}},
LabelStyle -> {Black, FontSize -> 16,FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}],After],
AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {+1, -1}, {+1, +1}}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black],
AxesLabel -> {"N-N/A", "Hydrogen bond lenght/A", "Energy/eV"},
AxesStyle ->Directive[Black, FontSize -> 16, FontFamily -> "Times"]],

ListPlot3D[{data2}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.4], PlotRange -> {9, 14}, 
Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> ColorData["DarkRainbow"]],

Graphics3D[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[10],Point[{3.23, 2.28, 10.12}]}].
Graphics3D[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[10],Point[{3.23, 1.7, 11.05}]}],
Graphics3D[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[10],Point[{3.23, 1.05, 9.6}]}],

AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 900]
```

which gives me this:

[3D PLot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ow6H.jpg)

[image]

Everything works fine. But I would like to **include picture of the molecule  instead of red points**, so it would look like this:

[Plot with moleules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibHme.png)

[image]

I know it is possible to load a molecular geometry from .xyz or .pdb or .mol. files

```
Import["D:\2dscan\mrci\1.mol", "Rendering" -> "BallAndStick"]
```

but how to include these objects into the plot?

I know I could do this in some graphic editor with png pictures that have transparent background, but I would still prefer *Mathematica* solution.
Problem is that, since I am very little experienced user, barely beginner, I dont know how to transform molecular geometry into 3D object that is possible to combine with the plots. Any advise is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Look at `Inset`.  What form is the result of that `Import`? (Do `Head@Import[]` if not sure )

Answer (score 1):

oddly you can not  `Inset` one graphics3d in another. 
Here is an example using graphics transformation to position a *Graphics3D* object in your `ListPlot`:

```
g = Graphics3D[{{Red, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]},
    {Blue, Sphere[{3, 0, 0}, 1.5]},
    {Black, Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0}}, 1/4]}}];
Show[{
  ListPlot3D[
   Flatten[Table[ {x, y, Sin[x] Cos[y]} , {x, -2, 2, .1}, {y, -2, 
      2, .1}], 1]],
  Graphics3D[
     (Translate[#, {-1, -1, -.75}] &)@*
     (Rotate[#, Pi/4, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}] &)@*
     (Scale[#, .1, {0, 0, 0}] & )@*
     (Translate[#, {-3/2, 0, 0}] &) @First@g]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

note the `@*` notation is fairly new, for older mathematica versions use `Composition`

reference:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102247/2079